# The Google Play developer page was changed?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Anyone know why the developer page from Google Play doesn't show anymore all apps of that developer? This changes occur from the last month, and I cannot find anything announced by Google Play team.

e.g. of occurrence: if I will search in the google play app by typing: pub: developer name, all the apps are shown, but if I click on the name of the developer from a specific app, it redirects on the developer page, and more than 90% are missing.

In the Developer Page, from Google Console, it says the following: If you delete your developer page, users who select your apps' "More by Developer" section will only see a list of your apps instead.

I think that who doesn't have a developer page active, the onClick events from the developer name redirects to pub:dev name, while for those with page active, redirects to the personal page, but without showing all the apps.

Comment: I don't see any issue in google play developer page, it's fine for me as I checked, try in some other machine or check using another account if you have

Comment: see my updated question